# How to use Dependency Injection in Angular 6 export function

Tags: angular

**I have tried this**

```
export function uniqueUserNameValidation(commonsService: CommonsService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise < ValidationErrors | null > | Observable < ValidationErrors | null > => {
    return commonsService.uniqueUserName(c.value).pipe(
      map(data => {
        return data && data.status ? {
          'uniqueValidation': true
        } : null
      })
    )
  }
}
```

**Common Services Method**

```
uniqueUserName(name:string){
        return this.http.get<booleanData>(constDefault.API_URL+"/commons/nameAlreadyExist/"+name+"/Tank")
}
```

**I am getting this error**

> core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'uniqueUserName' of undefined
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'uniqueUserName' of undefined

Comment: You can't. Just write a regular service with a method that returns an AsyncValidatorFn. Or write that function directly in the component which needs it, and inject the service in the component.

Comment: @holydragon no. It's because the commonsService variable is undefined: *Cannot read property 'uniqueUserName' of undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's automatic dependency injection only works for angular component constructors (which are being managed by the DI system).

As a solution to the specific problem shown in the question, you can inject the service into the component which will be calling the `uniqueUserNameValidation` and then pass the service as an argument to `uniqueUserNameValidation`. I think that, in general, this would be the preferred solution to your problem because it doesn't stray from standard angular practices.

Example

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private commonsService: CommonsService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', uniqueUserNameValidation(this.commonsService)]
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `CommonsService` is a proper Angular Service. If so, you could use `Injector`.

First import and declare the `Injector` in your module (app.module.ts etc.) and in the constructor of module init the instance:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

export let InjectorInstance: Injector;

...
...
...


export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    InjectorInstance = this.injector;
  }
}
```

Then in your file that is exporting the function, import the variable from the module:

```
import {InjectorInstance} from 'path/to/app.module';
```

Then you can use the `.get()` method of `Injector` to get the service instance:

```
export function uniqueUserNameValidation(): AsyncValidatorFn {

  const commonsService = InjectorInstance.get<CommonsService>(CommonsService);

  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise < ValidationErrors | null > | Observable < ValidationErrors | null > => {
    return commonsService.uniqueUserName(c.value).pipe(
      map(data => {
        return data && data.status ? {
          'uniqueValidation': true
        } : null
     })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: It's my bad. I forgot to add init code in the constructor. Edited the answer.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Hi, I added all the thins you specified and I get: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined". I have this in my AppModule: export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        InjectorInstance = this.injector;
    }
}. I have added this import in my ts file that has the export :import {InjectorInstance} from '../app.module'; And finally, I 'm using it in my export function like this: const translate = InjectorInstance.get<TranslateService>(TranslateService)

Comment: Hello @user3362334 Did you put `export let InjectorInstance: Injector;` in the `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: Yes, I put it below the imports

Comment: I also just tried putting the export function in the AppModule itself, and got the same error

Comment: @user3362334 Can you please provide a minimal working example with stackblitz.com or similar so that I can help you further?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz You can see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185220/problem-accessing-service-from-export-function/65185778#65185778. As I wrote in the question: I think I know where the problem is, just didn't know how to solve it. However, there was a better solution to my problem. But still, I'm not sure how would I solve it if I had to use the injector.