# Inject an Angular service into an exported function

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have an injectable service to show toast messages. I want to use it in another typescript file where i only have some exported functions.

Here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"; 
import { NotifierService } from "angular-notifier";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class Notifier {
  notifier: NotifierService;

  constructor(private notifierService: NotifierService) {
    this.notifier = this.notifierService;
  }

  notifiy(type, message) {
    this.notifierService.notify(type, message);
  }
}
```

And this is the exported function in which i need to show some toasts based on conditions. This is contained in another typescript file.

```
export function validateFile(file) {
let type = getFileType(file.name);
let size = file.size;
switch (type) {
    case "image": {
      if (size > 10000000) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

case "audio": {
  if (size > 200000000) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

case "video": {
  if (size > 300000000) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

case "compress": {
  if (size > 200000000) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

default: {
  return false;
}
  }
}
```

How to use the notify method from notifier service in this function??

Comment: Have a look at my older answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53479949/1331040) thread. Also I suggest you to consider the accepted answer if you want an alternative solution.

Comment: Why do you need that, I mean the services are created exactly for hosting this kind of logic, I mean why don't you create another service that will take care of the notify logic and have straight forward access to the DI and all registered services (including the notifier service)?

Comment: IT works. But it gives circular dependency warnings now. So i guess it's not the best solution.

Comment: You can create another module (e.g. InjectorModule) and create the injector instance in that module. Then import the newly created module in your app module. This way you can break the circular dependency.

Answer (score -1):

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"; 

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: "root"
    })
    export class NotifierService {
    notifySubject$ = new Subject<{}>();

     notify(type, message) {
        this.notifySubject.next({type, message}));
      }

    subscribeToNotifications() {
    return this.notifySubject.asObservable();
}
    }
```

===================

```
   export class SomeClass {

   constructor(private notifier: NotifierService) {}

export function validateFile(file) {
let type = getFileType(file.name);
let size = file.size;
switch (type) {
    case "image": {
      this.notifier.notify(type, 'some message')
      if (size > 10000000) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

case "audio": {
      this.notifier.notify(type, 'some message')
  if (size > 200000000) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

case "video": {
      this.notifier.notify(type, 'some message')
  if (size > 300000000) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

case "compress": {
      this.notifier.notify(type, 'some message')
  if (size > 200000000) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

default: {
  return false;
}
  }
}

}
```